# Explicit and implicit conversion

Tags: c++11, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, explicit, explicit-conversion

I am pretty surprised that this `struct`, which is only explicitly convertible to `bool`, works fine inside a `if` statement:

```
struct A
{
    explicit operator bool(  ) const
    {
        return m_i % 2 == 0;
    }

    int m_i;
};

int main()
{
    A a{ 10 };

    if ( a ) // this is considered explicit
    {
        bool b = a; // this is considered implicit 
                    // and therefore does not compile           
    }        
    return 0;
}
```

Why is it so? What is the design reason behind it in the C++ Standard?
I personally find more explicit the second conversion than the first one. To make it even more clear, I would have expected the compiler forcing to have the following for both the cases:

```
int main()
{
    A a{ 10 };

    if ( (bool)a )
    {
        bool b = (bool)a;
    }        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, inside `if` is like an explicit conversion to bool. (You can't be more explicit than using `if` to convert to `bool`!). http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> §6.4 Selection statements [stmt.select]
>
> 4. The value of a condition that is an expression is the value of the expression, **contextually converted to bool** for statements other than switch;

> §4 Standard conversions [conv]
>
> Certain language constructs require that an expression be converted to
>   a Boolean value. An expression e appearing in such a context is said
>   to be *contextually converted to bool* and is well-formed if and only
>   if the declaration `bool t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented
>   temporary variable t (8.5).

So the expression of the condition in `if` must be **contextually convertible to `bool`**, which means that explicit conversions are allowed.

This is mode most likely done because the condition of `if` **can only evaluate to  a boolean value**, so by saying `if(cond)` you are explicitly stating you want `cond` to be evaluated to a boolean value.

Comment: Thanks, I never heard about the concept of *contextually convertible* before. Can you please add to your answer in which cases is a conversion operation assumed to be contextual?

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 as the condition of an `if` `while` `for` statement. Other than that I would have to scan the entire standard. And is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108 found at a quick scan: the operand of logical negation operator (`!op`), operands of logical operators (e.g. `op1 && op2`), of conditional operator `? :`, the assert on a `static_assert`, no except specificator.